# Extract top-level key and contents from large JSON using stream

Tags: json, stream, extract, jq

One procedure in a system is to 'extract' one key and its (object) value to a dedicated file to subsequently process it in some way in a (irrelevant) script.

A representative subset of the original JSON file looks like:

```json
{
  "version" : null,
  "produced" : "2021-01-01T00:00:00+0000",
  "other": "content here",
  "items" : [
    {
      "code" : "AA",
      "name" : "Example 1",
      "prices" : [ "other", "content", "here" ]
    }, 
    {
      "code" : "BB",
      "name" : "Example 2",
      "prices" : [ "other", "content", "here" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And the current output, given that subset as input, simply equals:

```json
[
    {
      "code" : "AA",
      "name" : "Example 1",
      "prices" : [ "other", "content", "here" ],
    }, 
    {
      "code" : "BB",
      "name" : "Example 2",
      "prices" : [ "other", "content", "here" ],
    }, 
    ...
]
```

Previously, we would extract the whole portion of "items" using `jq` with a very straightforward command (which worked fine):

```
cat file.json | jq '.items' > file.items.json
```

However, recently the size of the original json file has increased drastically in size, causing the script to fail due to a **Out of memory** error. One obvious solution is to use jq's 'stream' option. However, I am kind of stuck on how to convert above command to a valid filter in jq's stream syntax.

```
cat file.json | jq --stream '...' > file.items.json
```

Any advice on what to use as a filter for this command would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside: Don't use `cat file.json |` -- that's making things less efficient (though it's not your memory-usage issue) because it's starting _two_ processes, a `/bin/cat` that reads `file.json` and writes to its stdout, and then makes jq read from a FIFO connected to `cat`'s stdout instead of being able to read direct from `file.json`. Just put `file.json` on the jq command line, or use `<file.json` to instruct the shell to give jq a direct file handle on the desired input file. `cat` is only for _concatenating_ multiple input sources; there's no point to using it when reading only one file.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, I'll be editing your question to take out the `...`s -- yes, it's important to let people know there's more input not shown, _but_ it's more important than that to make sure your sample inputs can be copied-and-pasted to test without needing to change them first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Charles. We perform piping since some small preprocessing is performed on the original file (so it is not exactly 'cat'). It indeed is not the source of the memory problem, but I will for sure look into preprocessing in a seperate process and executing jq on the new file without piping. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: One way to do what you're asking for is `jq --stream 'select(.[0][0] == "items")' | jq 'fromstream(inputs)'`, but starting two separate copies of `jq` is surely needless. I expect we'll see @peak along shortly to show how it's done properly. :)

Comment: Interesting. However I still don't understand the stream syntax completely, that command does produce results similar to the expected output, except for this command including the key "items". This last fact is not a big problem however and can easily be worked around. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a stream of the {code, name, prices} objects is acceptable, then you could go with:

```
< input.json jq --stream -n '
   fromstream( 2 | truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "items")) )'
```

This would have minimal memory requirements, which may or may not be significant depending on the value of `.items|length`

Comment: What is the reason for why you didn't give `truncate_stream` a `1` as input, which would have produced the `.items` array as one entity (as desired) instead of just a stream of its elements? Is it only because with the embracing array the memory consumption wouldn't be _minimal_ anymore, or is there more t it?

Comment: @pmf - Yes, the emphasis was on minimal.  If the size of the .items array is the reason the JSON is so large, then maybe the approach offered here will help.

Comment: Thank you very much! While both @pmf's and your solution work on my example JSON, only your solution works on my production JSON file. Would you have any clue on what could be the cause for this? And secondly, but less importantly, is it possible to include a comma between the {code, name, prices} objects, so I could save it as a list in JSON? Thanks again!

Comment: I did a little experimenting and changing the value '2' to '1' seems to produce results exactly as expected. Am I naive to assume this is a stable solution? I am not entirely sure of the implications of this modification.

Comment: By using 1, you are forcing jq to construct the array in memory. So potentially (i.e., at least in theory) you could run out of memory.

Comment: @sander Your original JSON file is too big to fit into memory. But if the `.items` array you are trying to extract, would, use either `1` or enclose the whole expression within brackets `[…]`. If, however, the `.items` array itself also breaches your memory, then stay with using `2` and keep handling the results in a streamy way. Also bear in mind that even if the former solves your problem now, there's no guarantee that it stays that way as next time your free memory may have decreased due to other processes and/or your original JSON file or, rather, the `.items` array may have increased.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `--stream` flag in combination with the `fromstream` builtin

```sh
jq --stream --null-input '
  fromstream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "items"))[]
' file.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "code": "AA",
    "name": "Example 1",
    "prices": [
      "other",
      "content",
      "here"
    ]
  },
  {
    "code": "BB",
    "name": "Example 2",
    "prices": [
      "other",
      "content",
      "here"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rJsqlK30oH) not for the efficiency or memory consumption but rather for the syntax (as I had to stream your original input using `tostream` for the lack of the `--stream` option on jqplay.org)

---

Note: Although it works for the sample data, do not try to shortcut using

```sh
jq --stream --null-input 'fromstream(inputs).items' file.json
```

directly on your large JSON file, as it only

> reconstructs the entire input JSON entity, thus defeating the purpose of using `--stream`

(clarified by [@peak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623635/extract-top-level-key-and-contents-from-large-json-using-stream/70624380?noredirect=1#comment124852874_70624380))

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Both of your examples work on my provided example, but for some reason only your second suggestion works on my production json-file. This second suggestion also takes much more time to execute, which isn't necessarily a problem but not desired. I will try to see if I can apply the first solution to a smaller version of the file and see if I can get it produce the desired results.

Comment: Also, what does the .[0][0] actually do?

Comment: Note that in @pmf’s most recent comment above, “—slurp” should be replaced by “—stream”.

Comment: @pmf - You could delete the faulty comment, and then (very sneakily) add the (corrected) comment, and then we can both delete the noise.

Comment: `--stream` transforms each "part" (scalars and empty arrays or objects) of the input into a stream of arrays with either one or two items. The first of them is always an array itself, representing the path to that "part", while the second one is, if existent, the actual value of that "part", or otherwise used as a marker to yield backtracking at the end of the current recursion depth. Thus, `.[0][0]` addresses the first item of any path array, which evaluates to the string `"items"` when processing (any "part" of) the `.items` array as it is located on the top level of your input object.